# Update query with current date and custom time not working in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

In this below query not working its shows error, please let me know what im doing wrong in this query

```
update tratbl set created_date = timestamp CURRENT_DATE + TIME '00:00:00';
update anothertbl set created_date = timestamp CURRENT_DATE + TIME '00:00:00';
update testertbl set created_date = timestamp CURRENT_DATE + TIME '00:00:00';
```

Error

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CURRENT_DATE"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use simple `= CURRENT_DATE`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b519f2eda06c60c80476b4fe51ab9df9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.10.2) says:

> To avoid syntactic ambiguity, the `type 'string'` syntax can only be used to specify the type of a simple literal constant.

Now `current_date` is a function, not a string literal.

A less complicated ways to write what you want is

```
CAST(current_date AS timestamp)
```

You could also omit the type cast altogether, because `date` will automatically be converted to a `timestamp` in an assignment.